# Python make method immutable

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class Hello(object):
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.names = names
    def getnames(self):
        return self.names  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    names = ['first', 'middle', 'last']     
    ob = Hello(names)
    a = ob.getnames()
    print a
    a.remove('first')
    print a
    print ob.getnames()
```

The following is the output:

```
['first', 'middle', 'last']
['middle', 'last']
['middle', 'last']
```

Is it because the method getnames is mutable? Or may be there is something else going on here. Can anyone explain?
How do I make the method return the original list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, assignment never makes a copy of a data structure.  It only makes a name refer to a value.  Also, function invocation essentially assigns the actual arguments to the argument names.  So nothing is copied in your code. The names `a` and `ob.names` refer to the same list.  If you want to have two copies of the list (the original and one to modify), then you need to make a copy at some point.  You'll have to decide where that makes the most sense.

You can copy a list a few different ways: `list(L)` or `L[:]` are the most common ways.

Answer (score 3):

have `getnames` return a copy:

```
def getnames(self):
    return self.names[:]
```

Comment: IMHO, this is too late. The original list with which the object was created might be modified outside this class, which would also change `self.names`, which is just a reference to the original list. Better to assign `self.names = names[:]` in `__init__`. Then the copy is made once, as the object is created, and there is no chance for Bad Things (i.e. external modifications) to occur during the object's lifespan.

Comment: Yes, that is true but you'd also want to have the method give out a copy too. As if you didn't you'd get the problem which the OP experienced. And that is what I wrote the answer to fix.

Comment: Fair point. It should be copied in both places, to guard against both kinds of inadvertent modification.

Answer (score 0):

The name `a` refers to the same array that's stored in `ob.names`. If you change `a`, you change `ob.names`, because they both refer to the same thing.